# Gettign the last <li> element to work the way I want it to

Tags: css, html-lists

Iam needing help with my footer in CSS.

I'm a new wordpress developer and I get the gist of how to work with it but as usual I've run into a problem, it's probably simple too, as I'm not sure exactly how to pick out the certain CSS snippets I need. I use Firebug but sometimes I just not sure whats happening with my CSS I guess.

This is my testing site so you can have a look at what I'm going to be talking about. In my footer, my last < li > element (the Archives) I'm hoping to get up right underneath Follow Us. I can always us the last child css rule however I know IE ignores that. So whats my next option? I know what to do if wordpress has given the lists individual styles but in this case it hasn't, so I'm not sure what to do.

CSS

```
#footer { width: 100%; height: 503px; background: url(img/FOOTER-bg.jpg) repeat-x; background-color: #821d20; position: relative; top: 100px;/*border: 1px solid #0C0;*/}
.footer-widgets { width: 960px; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/ }
.footer-widgets li { width:280px; height: auto; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; list-style-type: none; float: left; color: #fff; padding: 13px; margin-right: 10px; /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/ }
.footer-widgets li ul {color: red;}
.footer-widgets li ul li {color: #fff; margin-left: -50px; margin-top: -15px;}
```

What is the best way to make this work? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "This is my testing site so you can have a look [...]". Well, shouldn't there be a link then?

Comment: if you know what's going to be last, you can put class in it .footer-widgets li.last and make a style for it

Comment: @ambrelasweb, Do you have a link to share or was a suitable Answer found?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support browsers that do not accept a `:last-child` selector then you have two options.

1. Manually add a class to the last element and style it.
2. Use javascript to find the last `<li>` and add a class, then style it.

**[edit]**
Unfortunately, the very handy `lastElementChild` that was introduced in the [W3C Traversal Spec](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html) is also not supported in IE8/7. That leaves you, again, with two options.

1. Use a library like jQuery, which has very simple `$('.footer-widgets li:last-child')` selector
2. Use regular js and find the element through tedious DOM traversal.

I would say it's silly to use jQuery for this one thing, but if you will be doing other javascript stuffs on your site, might as well use jQuery, right? Otherwise, I would stay away from the DOM traversal as it's just a pain. Just manually put a class on the last `<li>` and be done with it :)

Comment: I've googled it but do you know of any good javascript snippet to find the last element? I'm not too familiar with javascript.

Comment: @ambrelasweb, Do you have a link to share or was a suitable Answer found?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 alternatives I see:

1. Add a class to your last element and take it with JavaScript to do your own manipulation.
2. Use jQuery to get the nested elements (unnecessary I think).

   Example:

   `$('.yourElement').css('property', 'value')`

Complement:

Getting any element with JavaScript:

```
  var x = document.getElementById("id");
```

I suggest you to take a look at [this W3C documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) with an example. Right after you get the element with JavaScript comes manipulation anyway you need it.

I think it may help you!

Comment: I've googled it but do you know of any good javascript snippet to find the last element? I'm not too familiar with javascript.

Comment: Please, check the complement I did above. I hope it helps you!

Comment: I thank you for the suggestion but as I said earlier I don't know javascript. So I was hoping you could point me to a website with a tutorial on it or something. Even if I were to try to get the element id, I wouldn't know how to get that as it's not written out in plain html and css but with has that snippet of code for wordpress to determine how to set it up. As when I use firebug on the <li> elements of the footer there are no pre-defined id's or classes. The suggestion you have there is getElemntById...is there a way to get the element Id and then ask it to find the last <li> ?

Comment: <li> is a normal html element, so if you modify it to <li id="any id"></id> you could use it normally with JavaScript as the example above. Considering you're starting with JavaScript, I'd recommend you this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org It's one of the simplest and complete.